# TFS build errors on non existent project file

Tags: tfs

I've inherited an application in TFS.  When I try to run a build I get an error message stating that the build cannot complete because it cannot find a test project.  The project doesn't even exist! The error message is below.

I've looked for any references in the TFS build but cannot see anything that points to this project.

```
 C:\a\src\Source\Projects\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Projects.Pipelines\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Projects.Pipelines.sln.metaproj: The project file "C:\a\src\Source\Projects\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Projects.Pipelines\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Proj.Pipe.ProjectClosing.Test\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Proj.Pipe.ProjectClosing.Test.csproj" was not found.
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the solution file in notepad and searching for the test project that the error references?

Comment: Do you have the test project in solution and check in it into tfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the solution is being built and the solution is referencing the test project (not the build definition).  I would try building the solution locally first if you haven't already.  Make sure you open the same solution file that the build definition references.

If the build is working locally you should ensure the source control path includes the test project path.

Comment: Is there a test project?  Are you sure you are opening the same solution being built in TFS?